# iPhone presents blank view on load

Tags: ios, xcode, view, modalviewcontroller

I am working on a Universal app (iPhone and iPad). I have a button that is supposed to bring up a settings view, and I have two separate XIB files, one for the iPad and one for the iPhone. I have the following code:

```
settingsView* sv=[[settingsView alloc]initWithNibName:@"settingsView" bundle:nil];
settingsView* isv=[[settingsView alloc]initWithNibName:@"settingsView_iPad" bundle:nil];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    [self presentModalViewController:sv animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"I am an iPhone");

}

if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    [self presentModalViewController:isv animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"I am an iPad");
}
```

This code simply shows a black screen on the device with the statusbar at the top. I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Hersh K. Bhargava

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this problem is, drag and drop empty two UIViewController in your Class.xib file. Create two @property (nonatomic, retain) ClassAVC and @property (nonatomic, retain) ClassBVC, make the connection to empty UIViewController's you just drop to class.xib file and also change the NIB name to the settingsView and settingsView_ipad nib file name. Then try

```
    [self presentModalViewController:ClassAVC animated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:ClassBVC animated:YES];
```

as well as

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ClassAVC animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ClassBVC animated:YES];
```